# Access external web server couchdb

Tags: python, couchdb

I search how access to an external web server thanks to couchdb but i don't find.

My web application is stored on couchdb (localhost:5984) and my pictures (format png) are stores on the wev server (localhost:5986) runs with Python.

So, i want to get my pictures via my web application. Here is my configuration for couchdb in the file "local.ini":

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
_maps = { couch_httpd_proxy, handle_utils_dir_req, "<< localhost:5986 >> " }


[httpd]
enable_cors = true
allow_jsonp = true

[cors]
origins = *
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (external, web, server) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: okay thanks for the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

once you access your db, you might want to consider building the url of each documents attachment as follows:

```
def function():

    couch = couchdb.Server()    #connect to server
    db = couch['img']         #connect to database which contains docs with img attachments
    doc_id = []                #create list of id's
    http_docid = []            #create list to populate href for picture path

    for i in db:                #for each id in the db
        doc_id.append(i)       #add to the carid list
        doc = db[i]             #get the document id
        for key in (doc['_attachments']):   #for the key in the doc '_attacments' payload
            print key #just to confirm
        href_docid.append(('http://yourdbDomain/dbname/'+i+'/'+key))  #create a uri and append to a list
    return href_docid
```

and using Jinja2 templating:

```
{% for img in function() %}

  <img class="some-class" src="{{ img }}">

 {% endfor %}`
```